# Retrieve public Facebook page via Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a possibility to get the feed of a public Facebook page? For example from https://www.facebook.com/AudiDE.

So far as I know, I can only access my own profile pages through the graph API by sending something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/feed?limit=1&locale=de_DE&access_token={access-token}&fields=id,from,status_type
```

So is there a way to get access to a public Facebook page by PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Are you sure? I think you can get the feed from pages you liked, also. I'll see it in the docs.

Comment: Didn't read it all, but seems pretty possible as [described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page), did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use an `App Access Token` or `User Access Token` to get the feed. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/AudiDE/feed?access_token=[app-token]
```

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Information about the Tokens you need can always be found in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#readperms